# Drupal View Template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I have a CMS system using Drupal 6 with a `Template.tpl` file which redirects each node to a customized template page. For example, the "about us" page node is directed to `aboutus.tpl.php` page:

```
if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == '1' && arg(2) == '')
{
     $vars['template_file'] = 'about';
}
```

Now, if I create a view on the back end, I try to make a customized page. Because the view is not a single node; what should I write that will display the view value on my customized design? Right now it is displaying on the CMS back end design only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of websites which will help you override a Views template file.  Here are a few to get you started:

http://drupal.org/node/394994 <-- see also resources listed at the bottom of this page
http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics